# Inheritance in Python, requiring certain methods to be defined in subclasses

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

In Java, for example, you can make a class MyClass with certain methods that are **specified but not implemented in MyClass**, but **must be implemented in any class MySubClass that inherits from MyClass**. So basically there is some common functionality among all subclasses you want, so you put it in MyClass, and there is some functionality unique (but required) for each subclass, so you want it in each subclass. **How can this behavior be achieved in Python?**

(I know there are concise terms to describe what I'm asking, so feel free to let me know what these are and how I can better describe my question.)

Answer (score 4):

A very basic example but the [`abc` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) provide a few more

```
import abc

class Foo():
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        raise NotImplemented

class FooBar(Foo):
    pass

f = FooBar()
```

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class FooBar with abstract methods bar
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't require the implementation of a method in a subclass in a way that will break at compile-time, but the convention on writing a method on the base class that must be implemented in the subclasses is to raise `NotImplementedError`.

Something like this:

```
class MyBase(object):
    def my_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError("You should implement this method on a subclass of MyBase")
```

Then your subclasses can implement `my_method`, but this will break only when the method is called. If you have comprehensive unit tests, as you should, this won't be a problem.

Comment: **-1**: _"will break at compile-time"_ - python has no "compile-time", so assuming you mean _"will break at declaration-time"_  -that's also untrue, as the `abc` module does exactly that

Comment: Of course Python has a compile-time. The source code is compiled to byte-code. There's no "declaration-time" in Python.

Comment: There is a compile step, but in normal operation it's part of run time. There is a "definition time" (which I assume Eric meant), which are instants at run time at which a class or function definition is executed.

Comment: That's playing semantics. There's a compile time, but there's no type-checking. For someone who is coming from Java and expects something to break at compile-time, the distinction is important.